# Cannot install ClickOnce - Certificate Not Trusted

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ms-office, code-signing

I am trying to publish a small Microsoft Office customization using Visual Studio 2013. I purchased a code-signing certificate from GoDaddy (issued by Starfield Technologies) and used it to sign the program. However, when a user tries to install the ClickOnce Manifest, they get the following error:

> Customized functionality in this application will not work because the
>   certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for RiskMP or its
>   location is not trusted. Contact your administrator for further
>   assistance.

The program is being downloaded from the same server from which the private key was generated and the same URL that was specified in the publish.

The only solution I have found so far is to add the URL to the list of trusted sites in IE internet options, but this isn't a very good solution as it requires a lot of steps on the part of the user. I'd like to simplify this installation as much as possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a way for Microsoft to secure the installation of Office solutions : This is the way Microsoft handles the office solutions : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772087.aspx