# Is our ClickOnce deployment guaranteed to work if we buy a certificate from a certification authority?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, code-signing

I am developing an office add-in application. We want to try the auto update function of the ClickOnce in the Visual Studio.

This is our first time to publish the software online. And we used a certificate created by ourselves to sign the software.  We met a problem. we put our software on our server, when we try to run the .exe file after we download this file from our server. 
It gives the below error:

> Customized functionality in this application will not work because the
>   certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for wordadd or its
>   location is not trusted. Contact your administrator for further
>   assistance.

Then we export the certificate created by the developer and import into the computer that we want to download the software. It would not show above error. It also can auto update. But we cannot ask our users to do this. It really inconvenient ask our users to do this. So we just wonder that whether this problem can be solved if we buy the certificate from the certificate provider.

Below is a question also about this problem, they still have this problem even they already bought certificate.

[Cannot install ClickOnce - Certificate Not Trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559048/cannot-install-clickonce-certificate-not-trusted)

Comment: I modified your question's title to what I think your question is asking. You can change it if my interpretation is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buying a code-signing certificate greatly increases the chances that your software will work as-in on your users' machines, but in the end it all boils down to the following question

> Is the certificate used to sign this application trusted by the machine?

The answer to that question is a definite no for your self-signed certificate, but it's not guaranteed to be yes for the certificate you'll buy.

The big / reliable certification authorities are trusted by default on most machines (see the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on a Windows machine), but if your user (or *big-corp*'s IT) removed the default authorities from the certificate store you're back to square one and you'll have to ask the user to explicitly trust your certificate. There's no easy workaround!

In the end, buying a certificate from a trusted CA will solve your problem on *most* machines but it's not bullet proof. You should be ready to support users who don't trust the default CAs by telling them to import your certificate.

Comment: Thank you ssssso much, Vache. It really give me some idea.